# How to make a tabular in a header ignore the environment set by the currently processed longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, fancyhdr

I have a tabular in my header, using `fancyhdr` and a `longtable` that take multiple pages.
The `longtable` has been created by an environment that also sets some variables:

```
\newcolumntype{|}{!{\color{white}\vline}}
\rowcolors{2}{greylight}{greynormal}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}%                             
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%                                       
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
```

The problem I am facing is that on all pages where the longtable is not finished yet, the tabular in the header will use theses changes.

Is there a convenient way, inside my header, to reset all thoses variables that could have been set ?

For now, I redefined those specific variables in the header, but I find it quite dirty and not very robust.

Comment: "I find it quite dirty and not very robust." Welcome to the world of TeX programming:-)  You are doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, you are doing the correct thing. LaTeX resets several things in the header but the list is rather ad-hoc and it's not that unusual that you need to ensure that the environment for any code that you put in the header is normalised.

Basically LaTeX currently restores the following things:

The document default font:

```
  \reset@font\normalsize
```

The normal space factor settings

```
  \normalsfcodes
```

Avoid writing label information on every page if a section head gets copied to a page heading

```
  \let\label\@gobble
  \let\index\@gobble
  \let\glossary\@gobble
```

zero out baselines

```
  \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit\z@

...
```

Default document colour

```
\normalcolor
```

Thus you will see that there is no notion of a single global resetting or a possibility of arranging the document scope such that settings within the page do not leak to the heading code.

Most multi-line headings will then also call `\@parboxrestore` either directly or by putting the multi-line code in a parbox or minipage. That resets some additional parameters.

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr}
```

So an alternative to resetting (say) `\tabcolsep` explicitly in your heading code would be to add its reset to `\@arrayparboxrestore` That would mean that any `tabular` nested in a `p` column in the `longtable` would get the reset values rather than the values used in the outer `longtable`. So it depends on your requirements...